# Python multithreading on EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Python app that creates threads via a for loop and I have a few questions regarding multithreading on EC2:

1. I would like to know if there is a limit on the number of concurrent
   threads on an EC2 instance?
2. What would happen if the maximum number of threads is reached or
   exceded? Is there a way to limit the number of concurrent threads in my python app via a setting like MAX_THREADS or something like that?
3. Does autoscaling allow unlimited threads on EC2?

Thanks in advance.

Note: The instance type is a General purpose 'm1.large' 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

You should consider an **EC2** instance as you would any other virtual machine- Multi-threaded processes are limited by the number of CPUs that the operating system can use.

**Autoscaling** allows you to spin up more instances on **AWS** based on certain parameters. It is not intended to increase the capacity of an existing one.